# How to get multiple spline line for a single group ssrs graph

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I like to achieve something like this.
[image]
Following is my dataset

```sql
CREATE TABLE #MonthData
(
temperature VARCHAR(200),
monthValue  VARCHAR(200),
StartTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #MonthData VALUES
('89'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 08:51:50.080'),
('0'    ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 08:56:50.533'),
('95'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:01:51.457'),
('90'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:06:02.070'),
('113'  ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:11:02.797'),
('101'  ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:16:02.727'),
('100'  ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:17:28.217'),
('96'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:22:28.517'),
('91'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:27:28.680'),
('89'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:32:28.707'),
('89'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:37:28.893'),
('88'   ,'5-April' , '2021-04-05 09:42:29.680'),
('111'  ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:47:51.467'),
('101'  ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:52:01.310'),
('94'   ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:52:31.647'),
('106'  ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:53:00.910'),
('99'   ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:54:01.797'),
('93'   ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:58:01.960'),
('89'   ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:58:32.193'),
('89'   ,'6-April' , '2021-04-06 00:59:31.497') 

SELECT * FROM  #MonthData ORDER BY StartTime

DROP TABLE #MonthData
```

I tried following

[image]

I group category by Start time.

[image]

Still the x-axis value is getting repeated.

[image]

Comment: I removed the 2 version tags, as they conflict. If you are adding a version tag, please only tag the version you are using.

Comment: Have you tried to specify a label interval on the chart's category axis?

Comment: Try adding a second group on the axis and remove the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could get to quickly was this...

[image]

To get this I only used the `StartTime` field as the category group. I did NOT use the `MonthValue` field at all.. (I also changed the temperature column to be numeric).

The on the horizontal axis properties I set as follows

[image]

Once the axis type is scalar things work as expected, I changed the interval type to Days and the interval to 1 .

This almost worked but the first date was not shown, so I used an expression to set the minimum axis value to be midnight of the earliest `StartTime` with

```
=DATEVALUE(MIN(Fields!StartTime.Value))
```

This basically returns the date part with a time of 00:00:00

If you want to only show the day and month then just format the axis label with a date format like `d MMMM` . You can access the format property in the properties pane under `LabelsFormat`

Comment: Work's fine Alan. 
One Question, How to remove the space in the x-axis label?

Comment: If you mean the space before the first data points then it's difficult. The axis starts at (in your case) 5th April at 00:00. So the space is the empty time periods. If you start the axis later then that first label will not appear. You "might!" be able to adjust it using the axis offsets but I'm not sure